# Can't debug async method even if I am awaiting

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following scenario:

in my Test class:

```
public class ControllerTests
{
    private readonly MyClass aux;
    private readonly Mock<IOrchestrator> _orchestrator;

    public ControllerTests()
    {
        orchestrator = new();
        aux = new MyClass(_orchestrator.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task MyTest()
    {
        var result = await aux.Start(new MyParameters());
        result.Should().BeOfType<AcceptedResult>();
    
    }
}
```

MyClass:

```
public class MyClass : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly Orchestrator _orchestrator;

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Start([FromBody] MyParametera parameters)
    {
        var result = await _orchestrator.StartProcessAsync(parameters);
        return Accepted(result);
    }

}
```

and at the end the Orcherstrator class:

```
public class Orchestrator : IOrchestrator{
    
    public async Task<Guid> StartProcessAsync(MyParameters parameters)
    {
        var guid = await MyLogic(parameters, async () => {
                var manager = _SomeLogic.Get<SomeClass>();
                await manager.StartAsync(parameters); 
        });
    }

}
```

while debugging the test I notice I am not able to hit a breakpoint in the Orchestrator class at the StartProcessAsync method. But I am awaiting everything! What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What is the test result? We don't see any indication of you assigning an `Orcherstrator` instance or a `MyClass` instance to the respective fields. Is the test succeeding? Also, the field in `MyClass` is typed `Orcherstrator` with an extra `r`, how safe can we be that you've reproduced the code verbatim enough for us?

Comment: Also, which version of xUnit are you using?

Comment: Ok, let's start with the low hanging fruits, are you attaching a debugger to the unit-test session?

Comment: @MindSwipe , debugger is attached and I can step till one level above, but not in the Orchestrator class.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , I did some mistakes sorry, I had to change a bit the code because it's company code. So I renamed some classes. But you are totally right and more details are needed. I edited the code to be more clear. I didn't post any further code about _SomeLogic because the problem I am having is that the debugger doesn't even step into the **StartProcessAsync** method from the calling **Start** method. Meaning that if I put a breakpoint on **var guid** it doesn't hit

Comment: And you have an instance in the `_orchestrator` variable?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I do, another line I forgot in the constructor and I just added, apologies. But everything should be fine in terms it is setup. The test succeeds correctly even. There is some misbehavior thread-wise that doesn't allow me to step into the orchestrator logic somehow

Comment: I think you need to mock the `IOrchestrator` if this is a unit test.  Then, `Orchestrator` is not involved at all.

Comment: Is this Moq or some other framework?

Comment: @Xtros it is Moq and yes also by mocking the interface itself doesn't make any difference

Comment: @Tarta Sounds very likely that your mock is throwing. Add a try/catch block around the `await` statement to catch the exception and see what the exception is. It could also be that the mocked method returns null instead of a task, try setup your mock to return a completed task.

Comment: @KevinGosse so, the mock is not throwing, tried to setup multiple try-catch and everything was fine. But I found out the second thing you said is right. My mock doesn't return an (awaitable) task but null. Right way, since it's a unit test, is indeed to Mock the method to return a completed task instead of leaving it like this, which would automatically return null (for which reason by the way?). Thanks a lot! If you write an answer I will accept it as correct one

Comment: Yes, you need to set up the mock, but still, you should be mocking IOrchestrator, not Orchestrator.